# How to check which image is in a UIImageView with tags involved, got 45 small images randomly picked by 9 UIImageViews and 5 picked by 5 UIImageViews

Tags: objective-c, image, if-statement, uiimageview, tags

I have 9 uiimageviews, lets name them small imageviews, in a container view and 45 images (9 images per group, meaning I have 5 groups). I also have 5 uiimageviews, lets name them big imageviews, animating upwards (in a superview) which, each, picks one image from 5 images... small imageviews pick 9 images from the groups based on the image displayed by a big imageview. Hope this is clear.

So the `if statement` below checks which image is displayed by small imageview1 and also which image is displayed by the moving big imageview, named movingRectangle1, then run whatever code I'm gonna execute in the statement section. I used `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to check the image but it seems like it affect the animation as I used it for all the small imageviews, 9 times per small imageview which makes it 81 (9 * 9) times per big imageview, how can I use tags to check the images, maybe it can help the animation to run smoothly when I call a method in the `if statement`. Any advice is highly welcomed. I am new to Objective c and spent 2 weeks trying to solve this, so please come to my rescue. Thanks in advance.

```
if ((touch.view == self.imageView1)
    && [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.movingRectangle1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_a)]
    && ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_b)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_c)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_d)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_e)]
        || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_f)])){

        // seems converting to PNG over and over has a bad impact on any method called here, big imageviews start to animate erratically if i call any method here
        NSLog(@"imageShape1 touched, correct view!");
    }
else if ((touch.view == self.imageView1)
         &&  ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_g)]
              || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_h)]
              || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_i)]
              || [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_j)])){

             NSLog(@"touched but Wrong view!");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare image data is very heavy process so just avoid this.

You should have tags for every Image and set in the UIImageView tag property and comparing them.

Comment: I use [UIView animationWithDuration:() Delay:() Options:() Animations:() Completions:()] method to animate the movingRectangles, in the completion block I call the method that randomizes the images for each movingRectangle and that happens to be at the bottom of the screen and its covered by a container (it covers from the bottom to almost mid screen, therefore the user would see the movingRectangle appearing at mid screen) with small imageviews. The small imageviews should show images that correspond to the image picked, so thats where I use the 'if statement' above. Thanks bro.

Comment: i) So would tags work for you or not? ii) where your images coming from (resource folder or through any web service)?

Comment: i) I hope they will work but I'm open for any advice or help. ii)they come from a folder I put in supporting files

Comment: Tags would work, so what problem you facing with tags then? there is a simple way out. assign enums for all the images and i)while setting that image in uiimageview, set the tag property of imageview equal to that image enum value and ii)when setting image of imageview from any other imageView, take image and tag both and set them. this way, all of your imageViews will have tag value associated with an image and then you will be able to compare them.

Comment: Well, I wanted to have an idea of how to use the tags to compare check the images, there is no much information about tags and enums working with images out there. Man, I tried. A little sample would help a new guy like me.